# Enabling button upon text entry

Tags: python, tkinter

New to Tkinter and a while since I did Python.
I have a page with multiple entry boxes.
I want the button to be disabled unless all boxes have text in them.
When it is enabled the button will open up a new form.

Here's the code:

```
    from tkinter import *

def only_numeric_input(P):
    # checks if entry's value is an integer or empty and returns an appropriate boolean
    if P.isdigit() or P == "":  # if a digit was entered or nothing was entered
        return True
    return False


def toggle_state(*_):
 if entry1.var.get():
     button['state'] = 'disabled'
 else:
     button['state'] = 'normal'

def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()


main_win = Tk()
main_win.geometry('500x500')
###################################################
second_frame = Frame(main_win)
second_frame.place(x=0, y=0, width=500, height=250)

Main_frame = Frame(main_win)
Main_frame.place(x=0, y=0, width=500, height=250)
###################################################


#I want it so that the button only allows the user to press it if the entry widget has  numbers inside. That
#will then open up the 2nd frame
entry_1 = Entry(Main_frame)
entry_1.place(x=200, y=50)
entry_1_check = Main_frame.register(only_numeric_input)
entry_1.configure(validate="key", validatecommand=(entry_1_check, "%P"))
                                     
button1=Button(Main_frame, text='Admin', width=20, bg='brown', fg='white',
       command=lambda:[toggle_state, raise_frame(second_frame)])


button1.place(x=0, y=0)
main_win.mainloop()
```

P.S this may not be preferred method but I am just figuring some stuff out :)

Comment: Please transform your code into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), right now `button`, `raise_frame`, and `Admin_login_frame` are not defined. For instance, you can replace the last two by a mock-up function that prints "show next page" or something like that.

Comment: With the last two I have code that calls those windows to replace the current window and they work fine. I just didn't include the code as it isn't relevant to the issue I need help with. The 2nd comment however I didn't realize I had called it twice, so thank you for that.

Comment: I guessed that, but my point is it is easier for people to help you if they can run the code, so it is more convenient for everyone if you replace the irrelevant functions by mock-ups.

Comment: Aww, I see, sorry about that. I have did the code a little so that it can be run. I am using an issue with the button not showing.

Answer (score 1):

In the description of the question, several entry boxes are mentioned so I made my solution work with an arbitrary number of entry boxes (4 in the example).

What should change the state of the button is when all entries contain numbers, therefore it does not make sense to execute `toggle_state()` in the button's command. On the contrary, it should be executed when the entries' content is modified.

My solution to toggle the state of the button, is to call the `toggle_state()` function inside the `only_numeric_input()` function so that it is executed every time the content of one of the entries is changed. However this means that the function is executed before the entry content is changed, so `entry.get()` cannot be used. Therefore I use a dictionary to keep track of which entry is empty: `not_empty = {<entry name>: bool, ...}` which is convenient because we can get the entry name with "%W" in validatecommand. I update this dictionary inside `only_numeric_input()` before executing `toggle_state()`.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import Entry, Tk, Button, Frame

def only_numeric_input(P, W):
    if P.isdigit() or P == "":
        not_empty[W] = P != ""  # update state of the entry in dictionary
        toggle_state()          # update button's state
        return True
    return False

def toggle_state():
    none_empty = True
    for b in not_empty.values():
        none_empty = none_empty and b
    if none_empty:  # all entries contain numbers
        button['state'] = 'normal'
    else:
        button['state'] = 'disabled'

def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

main_win = Tk()
main_win.geometry('500x500')
main_win.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_win.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

second_frame = Frame(main_win)
second_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

main_frame = Frame(main_win)
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

entry_check = main_frame.register(only_numeric_input)
not_empty = {}  # keep track of entries' content
# create the entries
for i in range(4):
    entry = Entry(main_frame, validate="key", validatecommand=(entry_check, "%P", "%W"))
    entry.pack()
    not_empty[str(entry)] = False


button = Button(main_frame, text='Admin', width=20, bg='brown', fg='white',
                state='disabled',
                command=lambda: raise_frame(second_frame))
button.pack()

main_win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I’ve been ill!! Thank you  I will take a look later.